# Javascript methods of a static object, declaring them externally degrades performances?

Tags: javascript, performance, static, static-methods

Just for curiosity, do you know (you might have already done tests) if methods declared outside of a static objects degrade performances than declaring them inside of a static object?

In code words:

do you know if this:

```
var SomeStaticObject = {};
SomeStaticObject.render = function() {...}
```

generates a performance degradation than this:

```
var SomeStaticObject = 
{
   render: function() {...}
};
```

---

I'm particularly interested if you go down deeper, imagine this situation:

```
var SomeNamespace = 
{
   SomeStaticObject:
   {
      render: function() {...}
   },

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Declaring them separately is faster](http://jsperf.com/static-object-methods). (at least in Firefox)

I cannot imagine why.

Comment: In Chrome it is vice versa (inline is 50% faster).

Comment: It seems that in my `Chrome 7.0.517.41 on Linux i686`, declaring them inline is 30% to 70% faster. So I guess this is a matter of browser.

Comment: That proves very little. Who knows what kind of optimization the JavaScript engine is doing inside an artificial loop like that? It's certainly not worth changing any habits for in any case.

Comment: @Felix Kling: where do you see that in Chrome is the opposite? The page http://jsperf.com/static-object-methods still shows declarong them separetly is faster like in FF. I did als an IE7/8 test, it's the same.

Comment: @Marco Demajo: With Chrome 7... on Mac OS X. Should also be in the results below the tests, but here is a screenshot for you: http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/4628/1011090001.png

Comment: @Felix Kling: hmmm I c. Eventually jsperf is still missing an important thing in the result tables: it shows browsers comparisons, but not OS. I did the tests on WXP.